# Challenge in using AsyncTask to avoid AndroidNetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, gson

I'm trying to use gson to connect to a server but i have a problem with the code, I found out that you need AsyncTask for network connections since it would not run in the main thread, hence the exception I got as stated in the title.

```
public class SendPostRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>  {

   private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();



   public String sendMessage(Object message, String address) {

       String url = "http://192.168.87.108:8080/MSS/" + address;
       String data = gson.toJson(message);
       HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);



       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("report", data));

       try {
           post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
       } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
           System.out.println("Your url encoding is shiat fail");
           e.printStackTrace();
       }



       HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpResponse response = null;
       try {
           response = client.execute(post);
       } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

       String responseText = "";
       try {
           responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
       } catch (ParseException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return responseText;
   }

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
      return "";
   }

 }
```

I am aware i need to move the code into the doInBackground method, but I also need to use the SendMessage method with its parameters by calling it in other classes to correspond with the server parameters(like save, register, etc), so i'm not sure how to go about moving the contents so it would work as an AsyncTask. Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Based on the title I thought I'd have my first close as dupe of the day.  You should just be able to call sendMessage in the doInBackground() function.  Its probably best to create the message you want to send in onPreExecute, then send it in doInBackground so there's no synchronization errors around the classes you want to use to generate the parameters.  But I think to give more help than that you need to be a little more specific about what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AsyncTask` takes one type of parameter, `String` in your case, so I changed `sendMessage` method to take `String data` instead of `Object message` (so you will just convert the `Object message` to JSON string before executing the task, it doesn't involve networking, and rather won't be very time consuming):

```
public class SendPostRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    public String sendMessage(String data, String address) {
        [..]
    }   

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return sendMessage(params[0], params[1]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Area[] og = gson.fromJson(result, Area[].class);
    }
}
```

All the network stuff must be done inside `doInBackground` method. Execute the task that way:

```
new SendPostRequest().execute(data, address);
```

Passing the `data`, and `address` the the `execute` method. `data` will be then mapped to `params[0]` and `address` to `params[1]` and accessible from `doInBackground` method. `params` variable is just an array of all arguments you passed to `execute` method.

Both `data` and `address` must be `String` in that case, because it is the type declared in `AsyncTask<`**`String`**`, Void, String>`.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot, but I am getting this problem at this line of code 

`Area[] og = gson.fromJson(request.execute(msg, "synch"),
      Area[].class);`

How do I get the return data in the form I need, it gives me this error: `The method fromJson(String, Class<T>) in the type Gson is not applicable for the arguments (AsyncTask<String,Void,String>, Class<Area[]>)`

Comment: @AlexandruPatriche To do something with the result of the task, you must use `onPostExecute` method. I've edited my answer and added this method. Also if the answer helped you, you can accept it clicking on the check mark under the votes count.